# Setting up a CSV Data Adapter locally

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to set up the Data Visualization extension to use data from csv file for the sensors based on this example:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/advanced_topics/csv_adapter/

So the csv data I am trying to use is the default Hyperion-1.csv in folder server\gateways\csv. Do I need to add/change some other settings as well?

It is showing the following error in Chrome console:

[image: Error message in chrome console]

I have these settings for the csv in .env file.[image]

And these in devices.json in server\gateways\synthetic-data folder.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just taken the following steps to enable the CSV data adapter which seemed to work fine:

1. Clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app`
2. Install dependencies: `npm install`
3. Create a copy of *server/env_template* and rename it to *server/.env*
4. Modify the contents of *server/.env*, commenting out all the initial env. variables, uncommenting the CSV-related env. vars, and setting their corresponding values:

```bash
# FORGE_CLIENT_ID=
# FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=
# FORGE_ENV=AutodeskProduction
# FORGE_API_URL=https://developer.api.autodesk.com
# FORGE_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:9000/oauth/callback
# 
# FORGE_BUCKET=
# ENV=local
# ADAPTER_TYPE=local


## Please uncomment the following part if you want to connect to Azure IoTHub and Time Series Insights
## Connect to Azure IoTHub and Time Series Insights
# ADAPTER_TYPE=azure
# AZURE_IOT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING=
# AZURE_TSI_ENV=
# 
## Azure Service Principle
# AZURE_CLIENT_ID=
# AZURE_APPLICATION_SECRET=
# AZURE_TENANT_ID=
# AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=
#
## Path to Device Model configuration File
# DEVICE_MODEL_JSON=
## End - Connect to Azure IoTHub and Time Series Insights

## Please uncomment the following part if you want to use a CSV file as the time series provider
ADAPTER_TYPE=csv
CSV_MODEL_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/device-models.json
CSV_DEVICE_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/devices.json
CSV_FOLDER=server/gateways/csv/
CSV_DATA_START=2011-02-01T08:00:00.000Z
CSV_DATA_END=2011-02-20T13:51:10.511Z
CSV_DELIMITER="\t"
CSV_LINE_BREAK="\n"
CSV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN="time"
CSV_FILE_EXTENSION=".csv"
## End - Please uncomment the following part if you want to use a CSV file as the time series provider
```

5. Run the app with ENV set to "local": `ENV=local npm run dev`

After these steps the app is running successfully, however you'll get some other errors because the *server/gateways/csv* folder only contains data for a single sensor (Hyperion-1).

Btw. I've been working on an alternative DataViz sample app that aims to be simpler and easier to reuse: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions-demo (which uses https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions under the hood).