# Problems uploading data from CSV autodesk forge

Tags: data-visualization, autodesk-forge, forge

Good Morning,
I'm using Forge Autodesk Data visualization API. I'm trying to upload the CSV data that is exactly in this format https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/blob/main/server/gateways/csv/Hyperion-1.csv, but what i get is internal error 500

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
 Hyperion.Data.Adapter.js?73b8:543 
    
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 Hyperion.Data.Adapter.js?73b8:543 
eval    @   Hyperion.Data.Adapter.js?73b8:543
```

It could be tha the problem is in the format of the csv file? this are my enviromental variables setted:

```
ADAPTER_TYPE= csv 
CSV_MODEL_JSON=server\gateways\synthetic-data\device-models.json
CSV_DEVICE_JSON=server\gateways\synthetic-data\devices.json
CSV_FOLDER=server\gateways\csv
CSV_DATA_START=  #Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z
CSV_DATA_END=  #Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000Z
CSV_DELIMITER="\t"
CSV_LINE_BREAK="\n"
CSV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN="time"
CSV_FILE_EXTENSION=".csv"
```

this is the code i'm using https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app

Answer (score 1):

I have just answered a similar question here: [Setting up a CSV Data Adapter locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72475891/setting-up-a-csv-data-adapter-locally/72528439#72528439). When you follow the steps listed in the answer the sample app should read the CSV data without problems.